# Client and server can not exchange data because both get "stuck"

Tags: c++, winapi, tcp, winsock, winsock2

### INTRODUCTION:

I have studied the MSDN examples for [blocking TCP server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737593(v=vs.85).aspx) and [blocking TCP client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737591(v=vs.85).aspx).

I wanted to try something simple, in view of modifying those examples to create simple chat application.

I have tried to implement the following, for a start:

- send message from server
- receive and display that message on client
- send response from client
- receive and display the response from client

### RELEVANT INFORMATION

I apologize in advance for the lengthy code, but i strongly believe it is relevant for me to submit [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) for both client and the server, in order for community to stand a chance for solving the problem.

I have tried to keep the code as minimal as possible, but did not want to omit basic error checking.

You can copy/paste both in single `.cpp` file, and they should compile and run without problem:

*Server code:*

```
#undef UNICODE

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <string>

#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT "27015"

int __cdecl main(void) 
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    SOCKET ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
    struct addrinfo hints;

    int iResult;
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN] = "";
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if ( iResult != 0 ) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
    if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Setup the TCP listening socket
    iResult = bind( ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    iResult = listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("listen failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Accept a client socket
    ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
    if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("accept failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // No longer need server socket, 
    // because I want to accept only 1 client
    closesocket(ListenSocket);

    // ===================== let us try to send a message...
    std::string message = "Test message from server !!!";
    int total = message.size();
    const int messageLength = message.size();

    while (iResult = send( ClientSocket,
        // send only the missing part of the string, if send failed to deliver entire packet:
        // we move the start of the string forward by messageLength - total
        // while we send remaining number of bytes, which is held in total
        message.substr(messageLength - total, total).c_str(), total, 0),
        iResult > 0)
    {
        total -= iResult;
    }

    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

/*  // adding this, seems to solve the problem ???
    iResult = shutdown(ClientSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
*/
    // receive response from client...
    while (iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0), iResult > 0)
    {
        printf("%s", recvbuf);
        memset(recvbuf, '\0', sizeof(recvbuf));
    }

    if(iResult < 0)
    {
        printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // cleanup
    closesocket(ClientSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    getchar();  // so I can stop the console from immediately closing...
    return 0;
}
```

*Client code:*

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <string>

#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")


#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT "27015"

int __cdecl main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
                    *ptr = NULL,
                    hints;

    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN] = "";
    int iResult;
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) 
    {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    ZeroMemory( &hints, sizeof(hints) );
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo("127.0.0.1", DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if ( iResult != 0 ) 
    {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Attempt to connect to an address until one succeeds
    for(ptr=result; ptr != NULL ;ptr=ptr->ai_next) 
    {
        // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
        ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, ptr->ai_protocol);
        if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) 
        {
            printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        // Connect to server.
        iResult = connect( ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) 
        {
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) 
    {
        printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // receive message from server...
    while (iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0), iResult > 0)
    {
        printf("%s", recvbuf);
        memset(recvbuf, '\0', sizeof(recvbuf));
    }

    if(iResult < 0)
    {
        printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // ===================== let us try to send a message...
    std::string message = "Client response...";
    int total = message.size();
    const int messageLength = message.size();

    while (iResult = send( ConnectSocket,
        // send only the missing part of the string, if send failed to deliver entire packet:
        // we move the start of the string forward by messageLength - total
        // while we send remaining number of bytes, which is held in total
        message.substr(messageLength - total, total).c_str(), total, 0),
        iResult > 0)
    {
        total -= iResult;
    }

    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // shutdown the connection since no more data will be sent
    iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // cleanup
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    getchar();  // so I can stop the console from immediately closing...
    return 0;
}
```

### PROBLEM:

I have implemented the solution, but did not get the expected result.

Server sends the message, client successfully receives and displays it, but then client gets stuck infinitely, instead of sending it's response to the server, which blocks the server infinitely as well.

### MY EFFORTS TO SOLVE THIS:

**First try:**

Using the Debugger, I have placed breakpoint after client's receive block only to determine client never gets there after it receives first message.

I believe `while` loop should call `recv` again, which should return `0`, thus forcing the loop to end.

Debugger doesn't even continue to show the content of client's receive buffer after I hit `Continue`, instead it exhibits behavior I can not describe at this moment since I am not a native English speaker.

**Second try:**

I have also tried to put receiving loop from server into thread, using `CreateThread`, but that did not help either.

I have also tried to put receiving loop from the client into thread, but that failed too.

I have tried to put both client and server receiving loops into thread, but that failed too.

**Third try:**

Finally, I have added the call to `shutdown( ClientSocket, SD_SEND)` in the server code, you shall find it at the lower part of the code, it is commented out.

This seems to fix the problem, but i am not sure if this is the right solution since i am just starting with Winsock.

### QUESTIONS:

- How can I bypass my "solution" of adding `shutdown` after `send` ?
- If the above is the only way, should I do the same after `recv` and what argument should I send (`SD_SEND`, `SD_RECEIVE` or `SD_BOTH`) ?

*Again, I apologize for lengthy post, but being new to this I have tried to provide as much info as possible in order to make your task easier.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a brief glance at your code I would venture to guess that the following code block in the client:

```
while (iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0), iResult > 0)
{
    printf("%s", recvbuf);
    memset(recvbuf, '\0', sizeof(recvbuf));
}
```

is actually your issue. You mentioned that shutting down the socket on the serverside fixes the problem. With sockets, the recv call is going to block as long as the socket is alive or until data comes through, but when the socket is closed you will get a recv of 0.

Instead of looping on recv, if you want to just receive *one* message you should either loop back to the recv call after processing the first recv or you should poll on the socket to see if there is actually data available first.

Comment: Or, simply do the sane thing in Windows, use [asynchronous I/O](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365683.aspx). Polling is not ever necessary.

Comment: *you should either loop back to the recv call after processing the first recv* I did not understand this part. Can elaborate on that or provide small pseudo code? Furthermore, I have discovered that indeed my loops are the cause of the problem, so I am working on fixing them.

Comment: What I meant is that if you immediately re-recv you could end up just blocking because there is no data available in the socket, so instead you should go process the data you just received (buffer it, print it, whatever) before you call recv again

Comment: I have rewritten both `send` and `recv` loops, and now everything works. Indeed, the way my `recv` loop is written, the only way to exit is to close socket, I understand now. I had to rewrite `send` loop, since I get the same behavior as before when I send an empty `string`. Now everything is OK. Thanks again, officially accepted and upvoted!